# Is there a way to halt an HTTP AJAX call in the browser so that another one can proceed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I'm working on an application that makes a lot of usage of AJAX capabilities. I'm currently working on a page where there are a large number of ajax calls made to render an initial page. All these calls are routed through the same AJAX script, so they have to be made one at a time by the browser. (Yeah, it's a bit inefficient)

I've got an event that loads another page, but unfortunately it needs to make an ajax call before it can re-render the page. The result of this is that if a user clicks on that link right when the page is first loading, the browser waits for all other ajax calls before making the call to re-render the page according to the event raised by the user's click. This has been resulting in some noticeably slow load times for the page when clicking on the link to it right as the page is loading.

My question is: **Is there a way to use Javascript or something to have the web browser cancel http calls to a web script so that another event can then make a call to that same script?** I know that it would be nice to make each call to different scripts so they could happen concurrently, but unfortunately the application I'm working on funnels all ajax requests through a central script, and that's not going to change anytime soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`abort()` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort-method) on the XMLHttpRequest object to cancel any ongoing request and return the object to a reusable state.

You could wrap it in a helper object, eg:

```
function HttpQueue(uri) {
    var queue= [];
    var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (xhr.readyState===4 && queue.length>=1) {
            queue.unshift()[1](xhr);
            if (queue.length>=1)
                next();
        }
    };
    this.send= function (data, callback, isurgent) {
        if (isurgent && queue.length>=1) {
            queue.length= 0;
            xhr.abort();
        }
        queue.push([data, callback]);
        if (queue.length==1)
            next();
    };
    function next() {
        xhr.open('POST', uri, true);
        xhr.send(queue[0][0]);
    }
}

var queue= new HttpQueue('/script');

queue.send('action=foo', function() {
    alert('task 1 done');
}, false);

queue.send('action=bar', function() {
    alert('task 2 done');
}, false);

queue.send('action=bof', function() {
    alert('task 3 is urgent! tasks 1 and 2 can get knotted');
}, true);
```

(not tested, may work)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery $.ajax method.

at which point you would specify a timeout for each call, and then set the aSync settings to false. That way you would only run one ajax request at a time.

Documentation can be found here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/